# twilio chat - add user to a channel and receive messages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am working on twilio chat functionality for an app.

Here's how it works:-
The users actually get registered to twilio when they login to our app.
and when I open the chat modal in our app, the user gets logged in to twilio also

Now, the way it's supposed to work is
the user loggedIn to our app can chat with other users on the app
and so a unique channel is created for the 2 users example unique Channel Name: UserA1_UserA2 i.e. if user A1(loggedIn user) wants to chat with user A2
other option for unique channel name is : UserA2_UserA1

and after user 1 creates the channel and joins the channel, he sends the messages he wants to send.

Now, when user A2 logs in to our app, he needs to join the same channel which user A1 has created
and there are 2 possibilities of channel names . i.e either UserA1_UserA2 or UserA2_UserA1

so, when User A2 logs in to our app, he needs to receive the messages sent by user A1

for which he will have to join the same twilio channel created by user A1 and then be able to load messages.

now, that's where I am getting stuck.

how does user A2 find out whether user A1 or any other user has sent him some messages
and he also needs to know which channel he needs to join to load the messages sent.

how does that work?

is there any way to do that??
I am building this functionality using reactjs.

I have already done the portions related to creating channel and login the twilio user
but not sure how to proceed next.

please let me know if you have any ideas.

I have followed this tutorial and have already been able to use it to send messages from user 1
but unable to get messages when I login using user2

How do I do that??

https://github.com/philnash/twilio-chat-kendo-react

UPDATE:

using this one - `this.channel.getMessages().then(this.messagesLoaded);`

Where messagesLoaded is defined as below: -

```
messagesLoaded(messagePage) {
    this.setState({
      messages: messagePage.items.map(this.twilioMessageToKendoMessage)
    });
  }
```

but after doing a lot of researching and going through the code again
I have found that the problem is not the loading of messages
but

it is to find the channel where the user has received the message.

so, like I explained above
say user A joins channel UserA1_UserA2 and sends messages there to user A2

but when user A2 logs in, 
how do we find out if someone has sent him a message on some channel
and also find out which channel. so that he can join that channel and get the messages.

that's the problem I am facing.

Comment: What code are you using to load the messages when your user joins a channel?

Comment: I have added some more code above.

But, like I explained above the problem is not with 
say user A joins channel UserA1_UserA2 and sends messages there to user A2

but when user A2 logs in, 
how do we find out if someone has sent him a message on some channel
and also find out which channel. so that he can join that channel and get the messages.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

**Update:** Apparently I missed this page in our documentation that describes exactly [how to enable push notifications for web through Twilio Video and Firebase](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/push-notifications-web).

Original answer with other ideas of making users aware of new messages below:

There's nothing inherent in Twilio Chat to notify web users of new messages within your application. What you can do though, is set up to [receive webhooks when new messages are sent to a channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/webhook-events). You can then check which user is not currently active in the channel, using [reachability](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/reachability-indicator), and then store something in your database against your user to say they have unread messages from that channel. Then, when they log in you can show them that they have unread messages, or you could, after a while, send them an alert, by email for example, to say they have unread messages.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering here. this was helpful.

about the channel - so you are saying, we need to do that via the backend ? 
say userA1 sends message to userA2 channel UserA1_UserA2.
When user A2 logs in ,webhook will get active. but wont contain channel info?? or if invitation received?

basically, this same chat is working on the android app version using the sdk .
what they do is create the channel and then add the user A2 to the channel as soon as they create it.
so I also wanted to do something similar so I guess it wont be possible.

do give me some guidance if possible

Comment: Webhooks happen at the time of the event and allow you to react to them, by storing data or notifying your user, at that time. On the other hand, you can always load the chat in the background when a user logs in, and check for new channels or new messages in channels, then notifiy them. It's up to you really.

Comment: so, I can setup something that 
when user2 logs in , they get notified whenever they get an invitation or a message.
right??
will have to see how to do that
Thanks

Comment: @philnash I'm confused when you say: "There's nothing inherent in Twilio Chat to notify web users of new messages". In the Programmable Chat docs there is a section on Push Notification Configuration (https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/push-notification-configuration) which allows for notifications for new messages and other events. Isn't this a valid option?

Comment: @faraz did you ever get this setup? If so, what route did you take? I have the same use-case as you (UserA1_UserA2).

Comment: @RyanBuening Damn right, I was completely wrong and unaware that page existed! I must look into this further  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @philnash any kind of documentation or demo app for this kind of scenario will be good

Comment: @Utpal have you checked the Twilio website?

Comment: yes I have checked it but not get any reference to star one to one chat communication..

Comment: A one to one chat on Twilio chat is a chat in a private channel with only 2 members: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006145008-Creating-direct-messaging-with-Twilio-Programmable-Chat